# Will everything be erased? And will I get caught?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, restore, cydia

Ok so I updated and I restored my iPod so everything about cydia on my ipod will be erased? If I go to an airport will they be able to tell that my iPod was jailbroken?

Comment: More importantly: will they care if it was jailbroken? Answer: no. Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131773/will-one-get-in-trouble-for-taking-a-jailbroken-device-through-airport-security

Answer (score 3):

Nobody cares about jailbroken iOS devices.

Even Apple only care if you take it for a warranty repair (as handing a jailbroken device to them and saying "this doesn't work" will probably get a response of "well, you jailbroke it").

I would say relax and don't panic.

To answer the first part of the question, doing a system Restore will remove all traces of the jailbreak. It's MUCH harder to jailbreak an iOS device than it is to remove a jailbreak :)

Comment: Thanks Scott i will relax and not panic. Thank you

Comment: Any time, no worries :)

Comment: Apple repaired my broken iPod Touch with Jailbreak - 2 Years ago :D They really don't care about Jailbreaks, except Hardware is damaged by the Jailbreak